# Multiple arguments with around advice

Tags: java, aspectj

I am given a method in a class like this..

```
public int foo(String a,String b){}
```

Now I want to apply a pointcut at this point and using around advice I want to alter the second argument.

```
public aspect Aspect {  
      int around(String s): call(int foo(Object,String)) && args(i) {
      int i = proceed(i.concat("hello"));
      return i;
      }
}
```

But I am not able to do so..Its giving me the error that Aspect has not been applied.
adviceDidnotMatch..

Any help please..I am stuck..:-/
Thanks in advance..

Comment: what exactly are you doing and what do you want to happen? I kinda dont understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `proceed()` and `around()` don't match.
`proceed()` should be called with both arguments.